# How do I get the "Measurement Units" setting from OS X?

Tags: macos, preferences, units-of-measurement

I want my app to display measurements in US or Metric based on the chosen setting in OS X's International preference pane.

How do I get this piece of information from the OS in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
BOOL usesMetic = [[[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem] boolValue];
```